# Positioning Apache traffic server between client and ISP

Tags: networking, webserver, apache-traffic-server

Can AST be placed between clients and ISP directly and used as a transparent proxy server? 
I don't intend to cache anything or hide my own web server. I just need to filter some content at HTML level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ATS can act as a transparent forward proxy. https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/7.1.x/admin-guide/configuration/transparent-forward-proxying.en.html